# Showing split arrays in a picture box

Tags: c#, image, display

I have searched through most articles and get the basic concept for how to display in a picture box. I have an array of both a filename for a card image as well as an associated value of the card. I need to display the cards in random order in 2 picture boxes. My shuffled cards were displaying correctly with the correct value, how ever both picture boxes showed the same image!
SO I split the array into 2 arrays and have now lost myself in how to display those in the picture boxes..that whole part is now red lined..Any suggestions?
Below is my full code

```
namespace lab4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string path = @"C:\Users\abura\Downloads\cardimages\";
        Image [] images = new Image[52];
        int[] cardValues = new int[52];
        int[] shuffledCards = new int[52];
        int computerCard = 0;
        int playerCard = 0;
        int[] values = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 };
        string[] ranks = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
                "jack", "queen", "king", "ace" };
        string[] suits = { "diamonds", "hearts", "spades", "clubs" };
             int currentIndex = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Setting Card Names
                for (int i = 0; i < ranks.Length; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < suits.Length; j++)
                    {
                        string filename = $"{path}{ranks[i]}_of_{suits[j]}.png";

                        images[currentIndex] = Image.FromFile(filename);
                        cardValues[currentIndex] = values[i];
                    }
                }
            //shuffle
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int k=currentIndex; k>0; k--)
            { int l = random.Next(k);
                int m = shuffledCards[k];
                shuffledCards[k] = shuffledCards[k - 1];
                shuffledCards[k - 1] = m;
            }
            //set into 2 decks
            var firstHalf=shuffledCards.Take(shuffledCards.Length/2).ToArray();
            var secondHalf = shuffledCards.Skip(shuffledCards.Length / 2).ToArray();

//here is where I redline!!
            Image[] playerCard = firstHalf;
            Image[] computerCard = secondHalf;

            pictureBox1.Image = images[computerCard];
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            textBox1.Text = cardValues[computerCard].ToString();

            computerCard++;
            pictureBox2.Image = images[playerCard];
            pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            textBox2.Text = cardValues[playerCard].ToString();

           playerCard++;
        }
```

Comment: > that whole thing is red-lined. work your way through the compiler errors and post the errors here. You're trying to assign `firstHalf` which is `int[]` into a `Image[]`

Comment: saw that an array cannot be converted to an Image[], akin to trying to use a string in an int array, however I was more trying to see if there was another variable I should be using to show my split int array into an image-first quarter doing code..

Comment: are you trying to do this? `var images = firstHalf.Select(x => Image.FromFile(...))` to get images from the int values?

Comment: @DLeh, basically I do want the "shuffled" image cards to appear in my picture boxes, I am also stuck on showing 2 different cards which is why I figured I could just split the "shuffled" array-whole thing is pretty darn bad I know...

Comment: You never actually select a single entry from `firstHalf` and `secondhalf`. A `PictureBox` can only display one image.